# How are sums and differences of independent Exponential random variables distributed?

Tags: random-variable, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

If we are given X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>,  X<sub>3</sub>,  X<sub>4</sub> , all exponential random variables with the same mean λ and said that another random variable T = X<sub>1</sub> + X<sub>2</sub> +  X<sub>3</sub> -  X<sub>4</sub>. Can we then say T basically has a  Gamma Distribution with parameters (2,λ)? I know we can sum up exponentials and obtain a gamma; however, I wonder if we can apply the same logic for subtraction. I think it is possible considering these random variables as arrivals to a Poisson Process, nevertheless I wanted to ask.

Comment: Hi: No. The sum becomes gamma but the difference doesn't become anything with a  closed form as far as I know. Note that when you take a difference, you can get a negative rate which has no meaning in the poisson assumptions-framework.

Comment: The fastest way to see that it can't be is to consider the support of the variable. Gamma variates are on the positive half of the real line but as soon as you subtract an exponential, consider that the one you subtracted has a change to be larger than the sum of all the ones you add, making the sum negative. (You could also see it by considering what happens to the variance using basic properties of variance, but the support is more fundamental)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the characteristic function of an exponential distribution is

$$\phi(t) = \frac{1}{1 - it},$$

when $X_1,\ldots, X_4$ are independent exponentially distributed variables (all with the same rate, which with no loss of generality may be taken as unity), the characteristic function of $X = X_1+X_2+X_3-X_4$ is

$$\phi_X(t) = \phi(t)^3\phi(-t) = \frac{1}{(1-it)^3(1+it)}.$$

Using partial fractions this is easily decomposed and inverted (by inspection or direct calculation of the inverse Fourier transform) to give the density

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{8} \left(e^{x} \mathcal{I}(x\le 0) + e^{-x}(1 + 2x + 2x^2)\mathcal{I}(x\gt 0)\right).$$

**This is recognizable as a mixture of a Laplace distribution, a Gamma$(2)$ distribution, and a Gamma$(3)$ distribution.**

[image: Figure]

As a check, in `R` I generated a million independent $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ tuples and plotted this histogram of $X_1+X_2+X_3-X_4$ to compare it to the graph of $f_X,$ as shown.

```R
hist(c(1,1,1,-1) %*% matrix(rexp(1e6*4), 4), freq=FALSE, breaks=200, xlab="x", main="")
curve(1/8 * (dgamma(-x, 1) + dgamma(x, 1) + 2*dgamma(x, 2) + 4*dgamma(x, 3)))
```

[image: Figure 2]

The agreement is excellent.

---

#### Generalization

Because the question refers to "sums and differences" quite generally, I thought it might be interesting to obtain a general answer.  To that end, note that the characteristic function (cf) of the sum of $k$ *iid* minus the sum of $j$ *iid* exponential variables will be

$$\phi_{k,j}(t) = (1 - it)^{-k}(1 + it)^{-j}.$$

The aim is to express this, if possible, as a mixture (linear combination) of Gamma cfs.  Recall that a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ has $(1-it)^{-\alpha}$ for its cf.  It is immediately apparent that $\phi_{k,j}$ is the cf for the difference of a Gamma$(k)$ and (independent) Gamma$(j)$ variable.  But that doesn't get us any further towards a solution.

*This problem turns out to be purely algebraic.*  Upon writing

$$a = \frac{2}{1-it},\quad b = \frac{2}{1+it},$$

observe that $1/a + 1/b = 1,$ whence $a + b = ab.$  Our objective, then, can be attained if we can express $a^k b^j$ as a linear combination of pure (positive) powers of $a$ and $b.$  (Formally, the calculations are done in the polynomial quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)/(a+b-ab).$ No analytic considerations of convergence, etc., will be needed.)

**The idea is to find $a^kb^j$ recursively.**

- The base case is $a^k=a^k:$ we already have a pure power of $a.$
- The next case is $$a^kb = a^{k-1}(ab) = a^{k-1}(a+b) = a^k + a^{k-1}b.$$ So, if $k\gt 1,$ repeat this process, ultimately finding $$a^kb = a^k + a^{k-1} + \cdots + a^2 + a + b.$$
- The next step shows us what will happen generally, using the preceding result to expand each of the terms that appears in the final multiplication by $b$:
  $$\begin{aligned}
   a^k b^2 &= (a^k b)b = \left(a^k + a^{k-1} + \cdots + a^2 + a + b\right)b\\
  &= a^kb + a^{k-1}b + \cdots + a^2b + ab + b^2\\
  &= a^k + a^{k-1} + \cdots + a^2 + a + b\\
  &+ \quad a^{k-1} + \cdots + a^2 + a + b\\
  &\cdots\\
  &+ \quad\quad\quad (a+b) + b^2\\
  &= \left(a^k + 2a^{k-1} + \cdots + ka\right) + \left(k b + b^2\right).
  \end{aligned}$$

Proceeding in this vein, we arrive at a general formula (which is easily proven inductively):

$$a^k b^j = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k+j-1-i}{j-1} a^{i}\ +\ \sum_{i=1}^j\binom{k+j-1-i}{k-1} b^{i}.$$

(That's rather a pretty relation in its own right...)

Upon dividing both sides by $2^{k+j}$ and re-expressing $a$ and $b$ in terms of $t,$ we obtain the desired decomposition, from which we may read off the Gamma shape parameters and mixture weights directly:

> $$\phi_{k,j}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k+j-1-i}{j-1}2^{i-j-k} \phi(t)^i\ +\ \sum_{i=1}^j\binom{k+j-1-i}{k-1} 2^{i-j-k} \phi(-t)^i.$$

For example, the combination in the question corresponds to a sum of $k=3$ exponentials minus $j=1$ exponential, for which

$$\begin{aligned}
\phi_{3,1}(t) &= \binom{3-1}{0}2^{1-4}\phi(t)+\binom{3-2}{0}2^{2-4}\phi(t)^2+\binom{3-3}{0}2^{3-4}\phi(t)^3\\&\quad+ \binom{1-1}{0}2^{1-4}\phi(-t)\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\phi(t)+\frac{1}{4}\phi(t)^2+\frac{1}{2}\phi(t)^3+\frac{1}{8}\phi(-t),
\end{aligned}$$

telling us the distribution is a mixture of $1/8$ exponential, $1/4$ Gamma$(2),$ $1/2$ Gamma$(3),$ and $1/8$ reversed exponential distributions.

Here is an `R` implementation modeled on the previous code.  It also includes a common rate parameter for all the exponentials.  (It played no role in the calculations because it merely establishes a common unit of measurement for all the distributions.)

```R
#
# Density of the sum of `k` and difference of `j` *iid* exponentials.
# (Equivalently, the difference of a Gamma(k) and Gamma(j) distribution.)
#
f <- Vectorize(function(x, k, j, ...) {
  g <- function(x, k, j) {
    i <- seq_len(k)
    sum(choose(k+j-1-i, j-1) * 2^(i-j-k) * dgamma(x, i, ...))
  }
  g(x, k, j) + g(-x, j, k)
}, "x")
#
# Simulated data.
#
k <- 9
j <- 4
rate <- 10
hist(c(rep(1,k), rep(-1,j)) %*% matrix(rexp(1e6 * (k+j), rate), k+j), 
     freq=FALSE, breaks=200, xlab="x", 
     main=bquote(paste(k==.(k), ", ", j==.(j), ", and rate"==.(rate))))
#
# Check by overplotting the density function.
#
curve(f(x, k, j, rate=rate), add=TRUE, lwd=2)
```

[image: Histogram with curve overplotted]

The positive components will have Gamma distributions with shape parameters $1, 2, \ldots, k$ while the negative components, when reversed, will have Gamma distributions with shape parameters $1,2,\ldots, j.$  As an illustration the next histogram, produced by the preceding code, also displays the components, suitably weighted and color-shaded to differentiate them.  Their sum is plotted in black, nicely tracing out the histogram.

[image: Figure: histogram with its components.]