# Deriving a gamma distribution from a Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

At the instant $t = 0$ a certain radioactive focus starts emitting particles. The infinitesimal probability that the focus emits a particle in the differential interval is $\lambda dt$. Let $N_t$ also be the random variable 'number of particles emitted by the focus in the time interval $[0,t]$'. Hence, we have that the probability distribution that $N_t$ follows is a Poisson one:

$$P_n = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}$$

However, imagine we wanted to calculate the probability distribution of the continuous random variable $T_n$ 'moment $t$ at which the focus emits the nth particle'.

How would we calculate this probability distribution? How would it be related to the Poisson one above?

I know it has to be a gamma distribution, but I don't know how to get to that conclusion.

Many thanks.

**Attempt**:

$$P[T_n \leq t]=P[N_t\geq n]=1-P[N_t\leq n-1] = 1 - e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{i = 1}^{n-i = 0} \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-i}}{(n-i)!}$$

How could I get to the following expression?

$$\rho_n(t)= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lambda^nt^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}$$

Comment: Hogg, Tannis & Zimmerman (I'm looking at 10th ed.) have a nice/accessible explanation for this connection.  It is §3.2 (on pp 100-102).

Comment: Welcome to CV! It suffices to show the waiting time between successive events is Exponential, because the sum of $n$ independent Exponentials has a Gamma$(n)$ distribution.  I derive this fundamental result from first principles at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214421. For the sum of Exponentials see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577324 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479 for example (Exponential variables have Gamma$(1)$ distributions.)

Comment: Thank you both @GreggH and @whuber! I've analysed both references and I understand the derivation.

Comment: If you differentiate $P(T_n\le t)$ w.r.t. $t$, you get a telescoping sum (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) which simplifies to $\rho_n(t)$.